# Rails : Extra column when using wice_grid

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I am using wice_grid in my RoR application. When I add attribute: to one of the columns, I see an extra column in the grid at the end with two icons that look like a funnel and calendar, which do nothing.

What is the column and the icons for? Or is it coming because my css is not properly configured?

Gemfile (showing here only the relevant gems)

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'wice_grid'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require wice_grid
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

application.scss

```
@import "wice_grid";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

UPDATE
I missed //= require twitter/bootstrap in my application.js.
After adding this line, the funnel and the calendar-like rectangle work. Their function is to do the filter and clear the filter.
Now the question I have is: is the extra column at the end normal wice_grid behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has the explanation, I had missed it:
*Filter related icons (filter icon, reset icon, show/hide icon) are placed in the header of the last column if it doesn't have any filter or a column name, otherwise an additional table column is added. To always place the icons in the additional column, set Wice::Defaults::REUSE_LAST_COLUMN_FOR_FILTER_ICONS to false in the configuration file.*